# How do I show an ACF group based on Elementor templates used in a page/post?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I've installed the ACF plugin by "WP Engine" on a WordPress site, because it was the first that showed up and was "installed" more often by a huge margin than the next result.

Now I've run into the problem that I only want to show an ACF group, that I created for a specific Elementor template, only when a page or post actually uses that template.

But I can't figure out how to set the filters for that, because it seems that the default filters don't offer something like that. And I lack the experience with PHP and Elementor to write a filter myself.

Is there a different Custom Field plugin that offers this functionality out of the box?

Or can someone point me at some resources that would give me the information needed to write a custom filter for the groups? I barely managed get the "tutorial" filter from the ACF guides site working, but that's it...

PS: I'm also curious why there's supposedly "native custom fields" in WordPress, but all guides on how to turn those on have UI layouts that don't match what I'm seeing here. Is that dependant on the current theme and not available in the "Hello Elementor" theme?